# Could an incorrect substitution result in a forfeit?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, fifa

In a football match, one team said that they would replace player A with player B, but they actually replaced player C instead, and continued to play the game. Is it possible that this would result in a forfeit under the FIFA laws?

Comment: I would guess forfeiture of fixtures will be regulated by the individual tournament rules. I've looked through the Premier League handbook and there's no such clause for this particular case, but a replay of a fixture can be ordered under various circumstances. If player `C` was otherwise eligible, I don't see how that could result in anything other than a fine.

Answer (score 5):

This could not be a forfeit under the [Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/development/education-and-technical/referees/laws-of-the-game.html) as the Laws make no mention of forfeits. So long as the referee (and other officials) are clear as to which player was being substituted, there isn't a problem here - and if the referee wasn't clear as to which player was being substituted, they should not have allowed the substitute to enter the pitch until it was clear.